# Folder permissions

Tags: asp.net, security, directory, file-permissions

How do I grant access to on an NTFS folder (Win2003) such that when files are added to this folder, they get the same access permissions?  My problem is that I have granted read access to the 'network service' on a specific folder but when I add files to that folder (programatically generate the files to this folder), the network service does not have read access to these files. I would have thought that the permissions cascade to the files in the folder? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: OK, seems that it has something to do with generating the files. When I copy in the files using explorer, the permissions are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the child objects in the folder inheriting permissions from the parent? Right-click the folder-properties-permissions-advanced.

And are you moving (as opposed to copying) the files in the folder? Move files also moves their permissions.

Comment: Cool, just realised that I am generating the files to a user temp folder and then moving them. So that is most likely causing the issue. Thanks.